# Is there any way to prepare a sql statement in Java without using a Connection object?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm pretty new to JDBC, so this is probably a very straightforward question.

I have to run several SQL statements, so I'm trying to write a generic "`runSQLResultSet`" method that takes a `String` sql statement and returns a `ResultSet`. I want it to take care of opening the database connection, executing the statement, storing the `ResultSet` in a `CachedRowSetImpl` object (so that it will persist after the connection is closed), and closing the connection. I created a method that does this and it works.

My problem now is that I want to be able to use it for dynamic statements that are built with variables. I looked around, and it seems that I should really change my method to take a `PreparedStatement` instead of just a plain `String`. Then I can build the `PreparedStatement` on the other side and pass it to the method. The problem is that I can't seem to create a `PreparedStatement` without a `Connection` object. I can open the connection before preparing the statement, but that defeats my purpose of factoring out the database processing into the `runSQLResultSet` method. I need a way to build a SQL statement with dynamic components, without a connection object, and pass it to a method that will then execute it. Is there any way to do this with a `PreparedStatement`? Is there any other statement object I can use instead? Otherwise - is there any better way to do this?

Comment: be forewarned the building "dynamic" sql statements without using PreparedStatement or something similar opens the door to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop - that's why I asked this question, instead of just building the sql statement with string concatenation and passing it in as a string, which would be convenient but dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create one without a DB connection. A `PreparedStatement` will be precompiled in the DB and thus really needs an open connection.

You can instead also just consider to dynamically build the SQL string instead. Generating the `PreparedStatement` placeholders (the `?` things) in a loop and and using [`String#format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to put them in the SQL string. u can also consider to just pass the variables to your `runSQLResultSet` method and build there instead.

As per the comments, here's an example:

```
try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
    setValues(statement, values);

    // ...
```

.

```
public static void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object... values) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have to pass the variables, it won't really be generic anymore. I want to be able to pass any sql statement with any number of dynamic variables incorporated.

Comment: Just pass them as a `Object[]` or as `Map`.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just use `PreparedStatement#setObject()`. An example (and more hints) can be found here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html Check the `DAOUtil` class example.

Comment: I can't read the blog as my office blocks all blogs... but thanks for the suggestion! It worked! (Although I used a variable length array - Object ... - instead of an array - Object[])

Comment: The `DAOUtil` class example uses exactly this. I've updated the answer with some relevant copypastes.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ResultSet excuteStatement(String statement, Object... params){
  statement = conn.prepareStatement(statement);
  int i = 1;
  for (Object o:params){
    statement.setObject(i++,o);
  }
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
  return rs;
}
```

Comment: PS. Remember to close your ResultSet and preparedstatment.

Comment: Thanks! This is basically what I implemented, as suggested by BalusC in his post and comments

Comment: Bad example. This way you can't close the statement anymore. If you close it, then the resultset will be closed.

Comment: @BalusC - I used the same basic structure but cached the resultset in a CachedRowSetImpl. I also stored the result of conn.prepareStatement in a PreparedStatement, not a String. But this was the general idea I used

Comment: @BalusC - I agree that i did not give the finer details. But there are many ways to do this... eg. pass through the preparedStatement instead of a string etc.

Answer (score 0):

what you are missing is the concept of Database connection pooling, you should never be instantiaing connections directly, the pool controls the database connections under the covers. You can look at my open source project [SQL Construction Kit](http://code.google.com/p/sqlck/) for some inspiration on one light weight way to deal with JDBC and how to build dynamic SQL statements using Factory and Builder patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the same query with different variables inserted into the query. You can have your method return the ResultSet like it currently does and pass the variables in as parameters to the method.

then you can put the parameters into the query inside of the method.

```
public ResultSet getResult(String param1, String param2){
 statement = conn.prepareStatement(yourQuery);// conn must be an open connection
 statement.setString(1,param1);
 statement.setString(2,param2);
 ResultSet rs = statement.execusteQuery();
 return rs;
}
```

That's a basic example of how you might do something like that if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: As I posted in a comment for BalusC's answer - then the method is not really generic anymore. I want to be able to pass any sql statement with any number of dynamic variables (and possible different data types) incorporated.